# How to install mongoDB on Fedora

Tags: fedora, mongodb

I want to install mongodb on fedora 25,

but i get this error :

Redirecting to '/usr/bin/dnf install -y mongodb-org' (see 'man yum2dnf')

Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'mysql57-community', disabling.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'mongodb-org-3.4', disabling.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'mysql-connectors-community', disabling.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'mysql-tools-community', disabling.
Last metadata expiration check: 1:58:49 ago on Thu Feb 16 12:55:42 2017.
No package mongodb-org available.
Error: Unable to find a match.

Comment: Connect to the Internet. You appear to be disconnected.

Comment: @MichaelHampton i realy have internet connection but it doesn't work michael !

Comment: I would check these instructions, and make sure you have completed all suggested steps: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/#install-mongodb-community-edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using this repository

```
[mongodb-org-3.4]
name=MongoDB 3.4 Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.4/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

It doesn't work on Fedora for two reasons:

- This repository is only for RHEL or CentOS 6/7
- `$releasever` should be 6 or 7 (and not 25+)

If you want to install mongo (v3.4 on February 2018) in fedora, you can use the normal repository:

```sh
# As ROOT
# Install the client and the server
dnf install mongodb mongodb-server

# If you have SELinux
# Allow access to port 27017 (the one mongo server uses)
semanage port -a -t mongod_port_t -p tcp 27017

# Start mongo server 
systemctl start mongod

# From any user
# You can access the client
mongo
```

Source:

- [Install Mongo on fedora](https://tecadmin.net/install-mongodb-on-centos-rhel-and-fedora/)
- [Official Mongo Documentation for
  REHL/CentOS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/)